# How pass data through the service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need to save data from one route and use it in another. I trying to do it with service.

Channel service

```
function channelApiService($rootScope, $http, $cookies){
    var _communityIds = '';

    return{
        setCommunityIds: function(ids){
            _communityIds = ids;
        },
        getCommunityIds: function(){
            return _communityIds;
        },

        channelCreate: function(callback){
            var token = $cookies.get('token');
            var data = {
                "token": token,
                "communities_id": this.getCommunityIds(),
            }
            $rootScope.httpRequest('POST', '/channel/create', data, callback);
        },

        }
    }
}
```

In route '/channelsList'

```
        // Create new channel
        $scope.createNewChannel = function(){
            if ($scope.communityList.length != 0) {
                communityApiService.setCommunityIds($scope.communityList.join());
                $location.path('/channelUpdate');
            } else {
                // To do nothing
            }

        }
```

in route '/channelUpdate' i try to get data, but it is empty string.

```
console.log(channelApiService.getCommunityIds())
```

So, how can i pass data from one controller to another? I found this method, but it's doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: try saving it as `this._communityIds = '';` and getting it with `return this._communityIds;`

Comment: Are you able to save the data with the help of communityApiService.setCommunityIds()?

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey doesn't help, now it undefined

Comment: @Rakesh Burbure  sure, please look at example, `communityApiService.setCommunityIds($scope.communityList.join());`

Comment: @maximus: what I'm saying is if it is setting the value correctly, you should get the value.

Comment: @Rakesh Burbure, for example `communityApiService.setCommunityIds('1,2,3');`
on another route i've get an empty string

Comment: @maximus Looks ok.. I hope you are passing this function to factory....

Comment: @Rakesh Burbure
my innatention, you are right, i pass data to another service, because they are similiar, not communityApiService, need channelApiService

Comment: @maximus No, you should inject the same service at the both the controllers. No need to write two different services. Different service means different scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Change `var _communityIds` to `this._communityIds` or use ES6 class syntax 
here are some references [classes MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)
and more [samples](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/classes-es6/). Here is a demo how your class can be look like

```
class ChannelApiService {
    constructor($rootScope, $http, $cookies) {
        this._communityIds = '';
    }

        setCommunityIds(ids) {
            _communityIds = ids;
        }
        getCommunityIds() {
            return _communityIds;
        }

        channelCreate(callback) {
            var token = $cookies.get('token');
            var data = {
                "token": token,
                "communities_id": this.getCommunityIds(),
            }
            $rootScope.httpRequest('POST', '/channel/create', data, callback);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `var` use `this` Please check below updated code

```
class ChannelApiService {
    constructor($rootScope, $http, $cookies) {
        this._communityIds = '';
    }

        setCommunityIds(ids) {
            this._communityIds= ids;
        }
        getCommunityIds() {
            return this._communityIds;
        }

        channelCreate(callback) {
            var token = $cookies.get('token');
            var data = {
                "token": token,
                "communities_id": this.getCommunityIds(),
            }
            $rootScope.httpRequest('POST', '/channel/create', data, callback);
        }
}
```